# PureScript の Array を降順に並び替えるにはどうすれば良いですか？

Tags: purescript

PureScript で Array を降順に並び替えるにはどうすれば良いですか？

現状は↓のように `sort` したあと `reverse` しています。

```
module Main
  ( main
  ) where

import Prelude

import Data.Array as Array
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console as Console

main :: Effect Unit
main =
  let xs = [3, 1, 2, 5, 4]
  in Console.logShow (Array.reverse (Array.sort xs))
```

もっと良い方法があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

`compare` + `flip` + `sortBy` を使った方法もあります。

```
Array.sortBy (flip compare) xs
```

- https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.0/docs/Data.Ord#v:compare
- https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.0/docs/Data.Function#v:flip
- https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-arrays/5.2.1/docs/Data.Array#v:sortBy